# How to turn a list into data frame (Google API Python)

Tags: python, api, dataframe

So the code below:

```
import argparse

from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types


def print_result(annotations):
    score = annotations.document_sentiment.score
    magnitude = annotations.document_sentiment.magnitude

    for index, sentence in enumerate(annotations.sentences):
        sentence_sentiment = sentence.sentiment.score
        #print('Sentence {} has a sentiment score of {}'.format(
            #index, sentence_sentiment))
        print(sentence_sentiment)

    print('Overall Sentiment: score of {} with magnitude of {}'.format(
        score, magnitude))
    return 0


def analyze(movie_review_filename):
    """Run a sentiment analysis request on text within a passed filename."""
    client = language.LanguageServiceClient()

    with open(movie_review_filename, 'r') as review_file:
        # Instantiates a plain text document.
        content = review_file.read()

    document = types.Document(
        content=content,
        type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT)
    annotations = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document)

    # Print the results
    print_result(annotations)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawDescriptionHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        'movie_review_filename',
        help='The filename of the movie review you\'d like to analyze.')
    args = parser.parse_args(args=['conversationforpython.txt'])

    analyze(args.movie_review_filename)
```

Creates the list of output :
0.0
0.0
0.699999988079071
-0.10000000149011612
0.10000000149011612
-0.10000000149011612
0.20000000298023224
0.10000000149011612
0.0
0.0
-0.10000000149011612
0.0
0.10000000149011612
-0.6000000238418579
0.10000000149011612
0.0
-0.4000000059604645
-0.30000001192092896
-0.5
-0.4000000059604645
0.0
0.6000000238418579
0.4000000059604645
-0.10000000149011612
-0.6000000238418579
-0.4000000059604645
-0.5
0.0
-0.4000000059604645
0.20000000298023224
-0.5
0.6000000238418579
0.0
0.0
0.20000000298023224
-0.20000000298023224
0.8999999761581421
0.10000000149011612
-0.10000000149011612
-0.10000000149011612
0.20000000298023224
-0.6000000238418579
0.0
-0.20000000298023224
0.8999999761581421
0.699999988079071
0.0
0.4000000059604645
0.6000000238418579
0.0
-0.6000000238418579
-0.20000000298023224
0.10000000149011612
0.5
-0.5
0.800000011920929
0.699999988079071
0.0
-0.4000000059604645
-0.6000000238418579
-0.10000000149011612
-0.20000000298023224
0.30000001192092896
-0.6000000238418579
0.0
-0.30000001192092896
0.0
0.4000000059604645
0.10000000149011612
0.4000000059604645
0.20000000298023224
-0.6000000238418579
-0.6000000238418579
-0.699999988079071
0.0
-0.699999988079071
0.0
0.0
-0.800000011920929
0.0
-0.20000000298023224
0.0
-0.800000011920929
-0.699999988079071
-0.6000000238418579
0.5
-0.4000000059604645
0.800000011920929
0.699999988079071
0.10000000149011612
-0.10000000149011612
-0.6000000238418579
-0.6000000238418579
0.699999988079071
-0.20000000298023224
0.20000000298023224
0.10000000149011612
0.30000001192092896
-0.699999988079071
0.6000000238418579
-0.699999988079071
-0.10000000149011612
-0.30000001192092896
0.20000000298023224
-0.30000001192092896
0.4000000059604645
-0.699999988079071
0.20000000298023224
0.0
0.6000000238418579
0.10000000149011612
Overall Sentiment: score of 0.0 with magnitude of 41.20000076293945

**Is there any way that I could turn the list/output into a data frame and export it as a csv? I am not sure which line produces the output so I don't know where to modify to make the output a data frame all the time**

Comment: Can you show expected data frame format?

Comment: I was hoping to convert it into a table.

Comment: What columns and how many should be in this table?

Comment: Hoping for two. one column for the sentence number like 1 , 2 ,3 and another column for the score.

Comment: It should have printed sentence 1 has a sentiment score of xyz with "print('Sentence {} has a sentiment score of {}'.format(
            #index, sentence_sentiment))" but i made it a comment wiht #.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what your asking ?
`

```
from pandas import DataFrame
your_list = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3',...]
df = DataFrame (your_list,columns=['Column_Name'])
```